# How to understand $\mathrm{Tr}(-1)^{F}=\mathrm{ker}\, Q-\mathrm{ker}\, Q^{\dagger}$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, operators, supersymmetry

The formula, $$\mathrm{Tr}(-1)^{F}=\mathrm{ker}\, Q-\mathrm{ker}\, Q^{\dagger}\tag{2.4},$$ appears in Luis Alvarez-Gaume's 'Supersymmetry and the Atiyah-Singer Index Theorem'. If my understand is correct, we can restrict on zero-energy states, which is finite dimensional. In this case $Q$ can be represented as a matrix (actually it is a zero matrix) and $\mathrm{rank}(Q)=\mathrm{rank}(Q^{\dagger})$, which implies $\mathrm{ker}\, Q-\mathrm{ker}\, Q^{\dagger}=0$. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Be aware that Ref. 1 confusingly denotes the operators $$Q:{\cal H}_b\to {\cal H}_f, \qquad Q^{\dagger}:{\cal H}_f\to {\cal H}_b,$$ and their trivial extensions to ${\cal H}={\cal H}_b\oplus {\cal H}_f$ with the same notation. Ref. 2 is better at keeping the distinction. In this answer, we will not use the extensions.
2. Let ${\cal H}_0={\cal H}_{0,b}\oplus {\cal H}_{0,f}$ denote the restriction of the Hilbert space ${\cal H}$ to zero-energy, which we split into bosonic and fermionic states. Then the restrictions $Q| :{\cal H}_{0,b}\to {\cal H}_{0,f}$ and $Q^{\dagger}|:{\cal H}_{0,f}\to {\cal H}_{0,b}$ are indeed just zero-maps, finite dimensional, and
   $${\rm rank}(Q|)~=~0~=~{\rm rank}(Q^{\dagger}|). $$
   However the kernels can be different because of the rectangular form of the matrices, so the index
   $$\begin{align} &\dim {\rm ker}(Q)-\dim{\rm ker}(Q^{\dagger})\cr
   ~=~&\dim{\cal H}_{0,b} - \dim{\cal H}_{0,f}\cr 
   ~=~&{\rm tr}(-1)^F \end{align}\tag{2.4} $$
   does not have to vanish.

References:

1. L. Alvarez-Gaume, [Supersymmetry and the Atiyah-Singer index theorem](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=supersymmetry+atiyah+singer+index+theorem), [Commun.Math.Phys. 90 (1983) 161](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01205500).
2. E. Witten, [*Constraints on supersymmetry breaking*](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=witten+constraints+supersymmetry+breaking+pdf), [Nucl. Phys B202 (1982) 253](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(82)90071-2).

Comment: I'm still confusing, on $\mathcal{H}_0$ both $Q$ and $Q^{\dagger}$ vanishes (say (10.109) in Kentaro Hori et al's 'Mirror Symmetry'). Thus restricting on $\mathcal{H}_0$ both $Ker(Q)$ and $Ker(Q^{\dagger})$  are  $dim \mathcal{H}_0$. So I guess the author was implicitly treating the restrictions $Q|_{\mathcal{H}_b}$ instead of $Q$ and its adjoint.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Examples), the rank of a matrix is equal to the rank of its transpose, even if the matrix is rectangular. I am clearly missing something, not entirely sure what though...

Comment: Thanks very much for clarification